# Let $p$ be a prime of the form $p = a^2 + b^2$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ an odd prime. Prove that $(a/p) =1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be a prime of the form $p = a^2 + b^2$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ an odd prime. Prove that $(a/p)  =1$

Could anyone give me a hint for the solution please?

Comment: Did you mean $\color{red}p$ an odd prime?  Then $p=a^2+b^2\implies p\equiv1\pmod4$

Comment: Are you allowed to use quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: Adding to that which @J.W.Tanner commented, a square number $k^2\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$. Therefore, given $p=a^2+b^2$, since $a$ and $b$ both belong to the same set of numbers as $k$, then $p\equiv 0,1\pmod 4$. But of course, $4$ cannot divide $p$ since $p$ is prime, yielding $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$. Edit: oh, and yes, $p$ must of course be odd, and if $a$ is an odd prime, it makes no difference.

Comment: $2$ cannot divide $p$ since $p$ is an odd prime rules out $a,b\equiv1\pmod4$ and $p=a^2+b^2\equiv2\pmod4$

Comment: @MarkBennet yes I am allowed to use quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner no I mean a is an odd prime not p ..... but since p>a , then p will be an odd prime also

Comment: Thanks; I figured that out

Comment: I think you know how that works now. Incidentally a prime number can be expressed as the sum of two squares only if it is $2$ or leaves remainder $1$ when divided by $4$. There is precisely one such expression for each prime (provided only positive integers are allowed).

Comment: @MrPie and why this leads to $(a/p) =1$

Comment: @MarkBennet and why this leads to $(a/p) =1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, so quadratic reciprocity gives $\left(\frac{a}p\right)=\left(\frac{p}a\right)$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95386/discussion-on-answer-by-user10354138-let-p-be-a-prime-of-the-form-p-a2-b).

Answer (score 1):

To explain further, we have that $p\equiv b^2 \bmod a$ from the given equation.

Quadratic reciprocity tells us that if $a$ and $p$ are odd primes and either leaves remainder $1$ on division by $4$ we have $p$ is a square $\bmod a$ if and only if $a$ is a square $\bmod p$. (and if both leave remainder $3$ modulo $4$ then precisely one of the primes is a square modulo the other).

Legendre Symbols are a convenient way of writing this - a notation - but it is important to understand what they mean. The fact that $a$ is an odd prime tells us that $p\gt 2$ is odd, and the fact that $p$ is the sum of two squares tells us that $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$.

---

For the first part we have $p=a^2+b^2$. Take this modulo $a$ and it gives $p\equiv b^2\bmod a$. That is simply what modulo $a$ means.

Comment: My problem is in a simple explanation of the first line you wrote in your answer why $p \equiv b^2 \pmod a$?

Comment: I do not have this understanding "we have $p$ is a square $\bmod a$ if and only if $a$ is a square $\bmod p$" ....... from where you got it?

Comment: @hopefully if either is equivalent to $1 \bmod 4$ this is simply quadratic reciprocity - it is what quadratic reciprocity means.

Comment: what about the first line?

Comment: @hopefully I have added a little to my answer. Your questions are about basic understandings of this mathematical language and fluency in its use. It is important to get the ideas embedded, but that is mainly done by working through examples for yourself. Suppose $p=29=5^2+2^2$ then $p\equiv 4\bmod 5$ and $p$ is a square modulo $5$. Also $p=28+1 \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. These two facts imply, by quadratic reciprocity, that $5$ is a square modulo $29$ and indeed $121=4\times 29+5$ so that $5\equiv 11^2 \bmod 29$. The point is that these things are always true.