# Why if the Legendre symbol satisfy $\left(\frac{a}p\right)=\left(\frac{p}a\right)$ then $\left(\frac{a}p\right) = 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol, quadratic-reciprocity

Sorry for my stupid question:

This is in completion to this question [Let $p$ be a prime of the form $p = a^2 + b^2$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a$ an odd prime. Prove that $(a/p) =1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271675/let-p-be-a-prime-of-the-form-p-a2-b2-with-a-b-in-mathbbz-and-a/3271678#3271678)

Why if the Legendre symbol satisfy $\left(\frac{a}p\right)=\left(\frac{p}a\right)$ then $\left(\frac{a}p\right) = 1$?

Comment: they could be $-1$

Comment: This is in completion to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271675/let-p-be-a-prime-of-the-form-p-a2-b2-with-a-b-in-mathbbz-and-a/3271678#3271678  @J.W.Tanner

Comment: You mean like, $(7|5)=(5|7)=+1$?  We know only that the symbols are equal iff at least one of the primes is o a greater than a multiple of 4, not specifically that they are +1.

Comment: So we have $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ here also @J.W.Tanner

Comment: @OscarLanzi we have here  $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ ...... what do you mean by "0 a greater than a multiple if 4"

Comment: @OscarLanzi This is in completion to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271675/let-p-be-a-prime-of-the-form-p-a2-b2-with-a-b-in-mathbbz-and-a/3271678#3271678

Comment: @OscarLanzi  we have here also $p = a^2 + b^2$ where a is an odd prime.

Comment: Hint: $(\frac{p}{a})=(\frac{b^2}{a})$

Comment: Got it because we are in a case either $b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ or $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ but not both at the same time ....... correct ? @Wojowu  thank you sooooooo much!

Comment: @hopefully I meant "one greater than a muktiple of four".  WHEN WILL THIS SITE ALLOW UNRESTRICTED EDITS OF ONE'S OWN COMMENTS?!?!

Comment: I think @OscarLanzi meant $\color{red}1$ greater than a multiple of $4$

Comment: @hopefully No, neither $a^2$ nor $b^2$ has to be $1\pmod p$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ (13|5) = (5|13) = -1  $$

........................

Comment: This is in completion to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271675/let-p-be-a-prime-of-the-form-p-a2-b2-with-a-b-in-mathbbz-and-a/3271678#3271678